# Accessing inner functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

How would I access `buildLoginUrl()` in my call to `login()`? The first `here` isn't being printed, and I think it's because the call to `login()` is never returned.

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // login function to kick off the authorization
    function login(callback) {
        console.log("here2");
        // builds the login URL for user after clicking login button
        function buildLoginUrl(scopes) {
            console.log("here3");
            return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + clientID +
              '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI +
              '&scope=' + scopes +
              '&response_type=token';
        }

        // other stuff
    }
// event listeners
    $("#login").click(function() {
        // call the login function, we'll get back the accessToken from it
        console.log("here1");
        login(function(accessToken) {
            // callback function from login, gives us the accessToken

            //buildLoginUrl(scopes);
            var request = getUserData(accessToken);
            console.log("here");
            request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
                console.log(body);
            });
            // other stuff
        });
     });
```

Console:

```
here1
here2
here4
```

Comment: You are not calling `buildLoginUrl` anywhere in your example. Where exactly do you want to call it?

Comment: You can't access it from outside the enclosing function unless you assign it to an accessible (e.g. global) variable or return it from the function. Why don't you declare it directly in the anonymous function?

Comment: `buildLoginUrl()` is never called so `here3` will never show.

Comment: Your `login()` function never calls the `callback` function and that's why `here` is never logged.

Comment: I can't change any of the code in `login()` because that was given to me for this problem, but I can edit the code within `login(function(accessToken))`. I don't think I have to call `buildLoginUrl`, but I'm not sure why `here` isn't printed to the console

Comment: Is this question on how to call a callback or on how to access `buildLogInUrl()`?

Comment: *"I  don't think I have to call `buildLoginUrl`"* If you don't call the function then it's not going to be executed, i.e. the instructions inside of it are not executed. So, if you want `console.log("here3");` to appear and do get the return value and do something with it then you have to call the function.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was asking the wrong thing. I'm trying to figure out how to print to the console within `login(function(accessToken)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a callback to login, but the `login` function never calls the callback. That's why you'd never see "here"

Comment: How would I be able to have the console print out the first `here`? There `here` between `var request` and `request.get()`

Comment: Call the callback anywhere inside of `login`.

For example:
function login(callback) { callback(); }

Answer (score 0):

> The first `here` isn't being printed, and I think it's because the call
>   to login() is never returned.

To keep it simple:

```
// here yo are defining login()
function login(callback) {
    callback();
}

// here you are invoking login()
login(function() {
    console.log('here');
});
```

`here` doesn't get printed because you never invoked the callback within `login()`; you have to call `callback` as shown above in order for `here` to be printed.

Comment: After reading these comments, I added `buildLoginUrl(scopes);` to the end of `function login(callback)`, but `here` is stil not printed, but here 1-4 are printed

Comment: You have to invoke the callback first before anything else for `here` to print.